# Redhawksdr Failed to connect to local domain

Tags: dns, redhawksdr, omniorb

I'm getting the following error while trying to connect

Failed to connect to domain: REDHAWK_DEV
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Error while executing callable. Caused by 
org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0

I tried

$ nodeBooter -D

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

and also

$ cleanomni

sh: 1: /etc/init.d/omniNames: not found

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.5 64bit with redhawk-src-2.0.3
Is there any solution?

Comment: Changing the version to 2.0.1 worked

Answer (score 0):

Based on the dialog, this was a network issue, not a REDHAWK configuration issue.  We will consider adding the text mentioned in the manual for clarification.